# Operator == cannot be applied to operands of type string and int

Tags: c#, winforms, search

So i have winform in which i have a datagrid with information in it and i want to search in it however i want the criteria of the search to be Year(int) of the product and its Type(string).

```
products[] a = new products[productscopy.Count];
int type = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
int year = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);

int br = 0;
foreach (products sl in productscopy)
{
    if (sl.Year == year && sl.Type == type) //line that causes problem
    {
        a[br] = sl; br++;
    }
}
if (br > 0)
{
    products[] b = new products[br];
    for (int i = 0; i < br; i++)
    {
        b[i] = a[i];
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = b;
    dataGridView1[0, 0].Selected = false;
}
else { dataGridView1.DataSource = null; }
```

Comment: What are the types of `sl.Year` and `sl.Type`? BTW - you have a typo there - it should be `sl.Year == year`, two `=` signs, not one.

Comment: sl.Year = year? you want: sl.Year == year

Comment: `if(sl.Year = year` that's almost certainly a bug.  You probably want `==` no` =`.

Comment: Is `sl.Type` is a type of string? You need to convert it first.

Comment: You parse the value of two textboxes as Integers, but you say that your product.Type is a string. Of course when you execute the comparison the compiler doesn't like at all

Answer (score 2):

Well...if the error is as stated, operator == between string and Int....i would assume that sl.year is a string, and year as I can see is an integer.  You either need to convert one or the other.  The problem could also be between sl.Type and Type...not sure which since you never provided the `productscopy` object for us.

Comment: He stated that `Type` was a string.  He's using `int.parse` on a textbox for the type when he probably should just be using the string.

Comment: Why not sl.Type == textBox2.Text (instead of int.Parse(textBox2.Text))? The author specifically say that Type is string.

Comment: which means that the error is comparing sl.Type to his local Type variable.  One is an integer, the other a string, and never the two shall equal :-)

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities...

Either `sl.Year` is of type `string` or `sl.Type` is of type `string` (or both)

In either case, the variable you compare to should be declared a `string` like so:

```
string type = textBox2.Text;
```

you might want to `.Trim` it if needed.

You could change the types of these underlying properties, or you might try appending `.ToString()` to see if you get the behavior you expect.

You also need to follow the suggestions above to use `==` rather than `=` but this is your typo not your problem because .NET won't compile otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what error says - there is no "==" comparison between `string` and `int` (or any numeric classes).

You need to convert one of them to type of another. Usually converting to stricter type is better, but may require more error handling.

In your case simple usage of non-parsed year from `textBox1.Text` (and possibly same for type) could be enough:

```
if (sl.Year == textBox1.Text && sl.Type == textBox2.Text)
```

or use int.Parse on text value (will need to handle exceptions if `sl.Year` is not a number):

```
if (int.Parse(sl.Year) == year && int.Parse(sl.Type) == type)
```

Note: your sample have `=` in year comparison, probably mistake.